# how do i get the last inserted column in sqlyog database without using top or last function?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a table named `tbltimpunch` that has the following columns:

- employeeID (not primary key/not auto inc)
- dateoftime (time of day)
- timein (the time input by the employee)
- timeout (the time of clockout)

It can be created with the following mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE tbltimpunch(
    `employeeID` varchar(10),
    `dateoftime` datetime,
    `timein` time,
    `timeout` time
);
```

How can I get the last `timein` or `timeout` input by the employee?

Comment: By last, do you mean most recent? By employee, do you mean filtering for an individual employee? Or do you mean grouping by employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT employeeID, MAX(timein) AS lastIn, MAX(timeout) AS lastOut
FROM tbltimpunch
GROUP BY employeeID;
```

This'll return a result set with a row for every employee (that has data in the table), along with their last timein and timeout values.

### Updated

This solution might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tbltimpunch t1
LEFT JOIN tbltimpunch t2 ON t1.employeeID=t2.employeeID
GROUP BY t1.employeeID, t1.dateoftime
HAVING t1.dateoftime=MAX(t2.dateoftime);
```

This will return the one row for each employee that has the latest dateoftime value.

Try the fiddle, here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca4f3/1/0

Comment: thanks for replying guys..i already figured out how to do it..but thanks for idea =)

Comment: @user2475486 If you've solved the problem a different way, please add your solution as a new answer in order to share it with other users of this site. You can even accept your own answer if it's the best one.